# add event to every button in a list of buttons

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a file explorer using tkinter and I'm having some problems.
I've made a list of buttons and I want that when I click each button, it will give me the address of the current path of the button. The problem is that it always saves the last path. Can I assign each button a path? here is the code I wrote (paths is just a class that I've made. It's basically a buffer):

```
def make_buttons(window, folders, path, paths):  # makes a list of buttons
buttons = []
for folder in folders:
    button = tkinter.Button(window, text=folder[len(path):len(folder)])
    button.bind("<Button-1>", add_new(folder, paths))
    buttons.append(button)
return buttons
```

Comment: Your bind wont work with how you have defined `add_new()`. Need to use a lambda or provide arguments separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a lambda in your bind where you call `add_new` or else the bind wont work when triggered like you may think.

Here is an example using lambda:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
buttons = []


def add_new(folder, paths):
    print(folder, paths)


def make_buttons(folders, path, paths):
    for folder in folders:
        buttons.append(tk.Button(root, text=folder))
        buttons[-1].pack()
        buttons[-1].bind("<Button-1>", lambda e, f=folder: add_new(f, paths))


make_buttons(['folder1', 'folder2', 'folder3'], r'C:\Users\Desktop', [r'C:\Users\p1', r'C:\Users\p2' , r'C:\Users\p3'])
root.mainloop()
```